# .htaccess shortening code not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, url-shortener

i would like to shorten http://fpmls.ca/index.php/user/user_postdetail/index/14 to http://fpmls.ca/index.php/post_14.html.

user_postdetail is a controller and index is a function of this controller 14 is id(dynamic)

My .htaccess code is:

```
RewriteEngine On           
RewriteRule ^post_([0-9]+).html$ index.php/user/user_postdetail/index/$1
```

I am getting the URL, but "404 Page Not Found: The page you requested was not found." is shown in that page. Any one please help me

Comment: `^` indicates the start of a url. However, your url starts with `index.php`

Comment: Also you are already using `PATH_INFO`, so can expand/dispatch the incoming URL suffix in PHP.

Comment: You should really be using the **routes** file for that kind of conversion/shortening. Have you not tried that yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `routes.php` in the configuration directory, define the following rule:

```
$route['post_(:num).html'] = 'user/user_postdetail/$1';
```

Alternatively, you can leave out the `.html` and make the your URI suffix in the app's configuration.

Comment: Don't forget to pass the param 'user/user_postdetail/$1'; :)